# How do I serialize an array of Objects into an array of Strings using GSON (with Scala)?

Tags: scala, gson

I have a web service that returns something similar to...

```
[ {...}, {...} ]
```

When I deserialize to an Object using scala I want it to be an array of strings not objects. So it would create an `Array[String]` that looks like this...

```
[ '{...}','{...}' ]
```

I tried this...

```
val list : TypeToken[Array[String]] = new TypeToken[Array[String]] {}
calls = this.gson.fromJson(this.response.toString, list.getType)
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to deserialize in this way?

Comment: do you have to use **Gson** or you can use other libraries? Also, does it has to be an **Array** or it may be other collections? Finally, are you sure your want inner strings or you want to parse it into a collection of some case class?

Comment: I can use other libraries but would prefer GSON since we use it other places to serialize and I don't want to introduce multiple libraries for the same task. However if it is cleaner....

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not too efficient but get's the job done

```
val list: TypeToken[Array[JsonElement]] = new TypeToken[Array[JsonElement]] {}
gson.fromJson(json, list.getType).map(_.toString)
```

Comment: Now that is clever let me try.

Comment: It did but I had to make it more explicit, it was giving me type errors so I had to split out the fromJson and the map

Comment: @JGleason if you found that useful consider accepting the answer as well, would be grateful :)

Comment: For sure let me finish a couple tests and edit the answer to reflect the changes and I will jump on that. Thanks again